# Pseudo-Streaming with h264 module and JWPlayer 6.*

Tags: h.264, jwplayer6, pseudo-streaming

Seeking your help once again.

http://www.sinbinx.com/node/3

I've got JWPlayer 6 on a drupal site using the following embed code:

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/en+DvHhyEeOGlCIACmOLpg.js"></script>
<div id='playeroyfomDKQiRBb'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('playeroyfomDKQiRBb').setup({
    file: 'http://h264.code-shop.com/demo/apache/workers_world_co64_box64.mp4',
    //file: 'http://www.sinbinx.com/sites/sinbinx.com/files/video/43818689.mp4',
    image: 'http://www.sinbinx.com/sites/sinbinx.com/files/no-video-img.png',
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: '16:9',
    startparam: 'starttime',
    //fallback: 'false',
    primary: 'flash'
});
```

Followed all of the JWPlayer docs for pseudo streaming and I'm even testing with a .mp4 that was used on one of the examples so I know that'll be sent via a server with Pseudo streaming capabilities. Namely Apache modH264 streaming module.

For some reason thought whilst the player seeks ahead the and the request parameter is added to the video request (start - Note: I've also tried starttime) It just doesn't respond with the correct part of the video. Rather it acts like a new request for file.

NOTE: It's flash I have an issue with. HTML5 is fine.

Any Ideas welcome please.

Answer (score 0):

i think your mod is not properly installed or your mp4 doesn't had a metadata.
if you are really sure that your modh264_streaming is works, then the only thing that you cannot seek is that your mp4 file doesn't contain a METADATA for seeking.